# .find() method skips table just after parent

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

When I hit `Inner Add row` it adds the correct row from the `.charts-series` table but if I hit  `Outer Add Row` it adds a row from the `.charts-series` table instead of a row from the `.charts` table. Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cbMHk/5/

HTML:

```
<div class='cont'>
    <table class="charts" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="2px solid #000000" align="center">
        <thead class="charts">
            <tr class="charts charts-first charts-last even">
                <th class="charts charts-first charts-tr-header" width="5%">#</th>
                <th class="charts" width="40%">Name</th>
                <th class="charts charts-last">serie_points</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="charts">
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="charts charts-first">1</td>
                <td class="charts">
                    <input name="" placeholder="place_series_name" />
                </td>
                <td class="charts">
                    <table class="charts-series" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" align="center">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="even">
                                <th width="20px" />
                                <th>value</th>
                                <th>seria_point</th>
                                <th/>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="odd">
                                <td class="first">1</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="" placeholder="0" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="" placeholder="0" />
                                </td>
                                <td class="last"><a class="remove-btn remove" title="Remove row" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
<a class="add-btn add" title="Add row">Inner Add Row</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<a class="add-btn add" title="Add row"> Outer Add Row</a>

</div>
```

JS:

```
    $('.add-btn').live('click', function(){
        var prev = $(this).parent().find('table tbody');
        prev.find('tr:last').clone().appendTo( prev ).find('input').val('');
        return false;
    });
```

when I check `$(this).parent()` it appears correct. What is wrong?

Comment: first of all dont use live, use on. Second, why dont you create two event handlers. One for each link/button?

Comment: @AlexShilman check the fiddle, OP is using older version of jquery so there is no problem.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan: OP is using 1.7.2 in the fiddle. [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was deprecated as of 1.7.

Comment: yes, can't use `on` as well as there is old jquery version on that website

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan Yeah i later noticed that it merged the edit.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use children instead of find. find is going to go deep and find for your selector, you dont want that in your case.

```
    var prev = $(this).prev('table').children('tbody');
    prev.children('tr:last').clone().appendTo(prev).find('input').val('');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kcvK3/)**

To add on `live` has been deprecated and instead you can use the event delegation syntax of [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject) by binding the event to the container element (or event document head) that exists in DOM at any given time as long as you need the event.

```
 $('.cont').on('click', '.add-btn', function () {
     .....
  }
```